# Скругление углов у ImageButton

Tags: android, button

Помогите закруглить углы у Image Button

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bottle"
        android:src="@drawable/bottle"
        android:background="@drawable/rouncorners"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">


<corners android:radius="10dp"/>

</shape>
```

Answer (score 4):

Надо еще в коде вызвать:

```
ImageView.setClipToOutline(true);
```

иначе `ImageView` не будет обрезаться по границам фона (то есть будет с острыми углами)

Как альтернативу можно использовать [RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView):

```
<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:src="@drawable/photo1"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:riv_corner_radius="30dip"
/>
```