# Установить фон кнопки

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Установить картинку из ресурсов drawable  как фон кнопки.

Comment: А что конкретно у вас не получилось и как вы пытались решить проблему?

Comment: @AntonSorokin я пытался с помошью метода setBackground но почему то он не принимает значения из ресурсов

Comment: Обязательно кнопку ? Можно сделать картинку clickable.

Comment: @GinTasan кнопку обязательно ,а что обозначает clickable

Comment: @GinTasan Я просто новичок

Comment: @danchik202020 , надеюсь помог )

Comment: Добавьте код, который у вас есть

Comment: а можно ли в качестве фона присвоить xml файл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817608/when-should-one-use-androidclickable

---

Как указано в документации, и насколько я знаю:

```
clickable - определяет, реагирует ли это представление на события кликов. Должно быть логическое значение, либо "true", либо "false".
```

Так, например, если вы просто объявляете Webview или View в своем layout.xml и пытаетесь установить OnClickListener в этих представлениях, событие OnClick не будет запущено, если вы не укажете атрибут:

android:clickable=true

По поводу clickable.

---

В андроид есть ImageButton

Ресурсы:

https://android-tools.ru/coding/delaem-krasivye-knopki-v-android/

Вы сказали , что новичек - есть не плохой сайт, очень рекомендую, для начинающих по андроид самое то -

https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html

И , конечно желательно иметь базу знаний по Java

http://padabum.com/d.php?id=175581

Еще ресурс по TextView и clickable

http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/textview.php#onclick

Что бы сделать изображение - кнопку используйте [ImageButton](https://android-tools.ru/coding/delaem-krasivye-knopki-v-android/)
Чтобы установить изображение, вы можете использовать атрибут src.

View в layout файле можно присвоить свойство clickable, с помощью которого можно устанавливать обработчик нажатий на View элемент, и не пользоваться только кнопками 
Вы можете отображать на Button вместе с текстом изображение, используя drawableTop, drawableRight, drawableBottom или drawableLeft , от этого будет зависеть где будет расположен рисунок.

Comment: View в layout файле можно присвоить свойство clickable , с помощью которого можно устанавливать обработчик нажатий на View элемент, и не пользоваться только кнопками - я скинул ссылки на сайты, где все подробно расписано,

Comment: Вы можете отображать на  Button вместе с текстом изображение, используя drawableTop, drawableRight, drawableBottom или drawableLeft , от этого будет зависеть где будет расположен рисунок

Comment: а по другому нельзя присвоить кнопке фон в java

Comment: ImageButton есть, она предназначена для таких операций с картинками , как я отписал выше, ссылка на сайт - https://android-tools.ru/coding/delaem-krasivye-knopki-v-android/

Comment: "Gin Tasan а можно ли в качестве фона присвоить xml файл

Comment: @danchik202020, а что вы хотите реализовать ? И вот что получается когда XML присваивают как background https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645810/imagebutton-background-with-xml

Comment: мне нужно чтобы я через java код мог менять фон. фон этот будет в xml файле потому что у него должны быть закруглены края

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756871/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%83-imagebutton , https://android-tools.ru/coding/delaem-krasivye-knopki-v-android/ , http://www.ohandroid.com/imagebutton-13.html ,http://[q]aru.site/questions/8760564/android-imagebutton-how-to-change-the-image-when-button-is-clicked  - уберите [] в названии сайта.   Сайты помогут  При нажатии и отпускании на ImageButton менять изображения, менять его по нажатию на кнопку, и закруглять ImageButton